# addition of numeric columns from different dataframes using a common date indexing column

Tags: r, dataframe

There are several R dataframes with the same two columns: "YMD", "Amount" as following

```
a <- data.frame(YMD = as.Date(c("2012-02-01", "2014-03-04", "2015-05-08")), Amount = c(100, 200, 300))
b <- data.frame(YMD = as.Date(c("2012-02-01", "2013-11-08", "2016-09-01")), Amount = c(10, 20, 30))
c <- data.frame(YMD = as.Date(c("2013-04-10", "2013-11-08", "2016-09-01")), Amount = c(1, 2, 3))

> a
         YMD Amount
1 2012-02-01    100
2 2014-03-04    200
3 2015-05-08    300

> b
         YMD Amount
1 2012-02-01     10
2 2013-11-08     20
3 2016-09-01     30

> c
         YMD Amount
1 2013-04-10      1
2 2013-11-08      2
3 2016-09-01      3
```

please teach me how to get the following outcome when some kind of addtion is applied to the above 3 dataframes

```
         YMD Amount
1 2012-02-01    110
2 2013-11-08     22
3 2014-03-04    200
4 2015-05-08    300
5 2016-09-01     33
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` after placing the 'data.frame's' in a `list`, then grouped by 'YMD', we get the `sum` of 'Amount'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(a,b,c))[, .(Amount = sum(Amount)), by = YMD]
#          YMD Amount
#1: 2012-02-01    110
#2: 2014-03-04    200
#3: 2015-05-08    300
#4: 2013-11-08     22
#5: 2016-09-01     33
#6: 2013-04-10      1
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we can do the same with `bind_rows` and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a,b,c) %>%
         group_by(YMD) %>%
         summarise(Amount = sum(Amount))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
abc <- rbind(a, b, c)
aggregate(abc$Amount, by = list(abc$YMD), FUN = "sum")
# Group.1   x
# 1 2012-02-01 110
# 2 2013-04-10   1
# 3 2013-11-08  22
# 4 2014-03-04 200
# 5 2015-05-08 300
# 6 2016-09-01  33
```